# Coordinating backgroundworkers

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Beginner here- I'm building a testing station and I'm having trouble coordinating backgroundworkers. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Dim start as boolean = false

click start button
backgroundworker1.runworkerasync()
backgroundworker2.runworkerasync()



backgroundworker1.dowork

   Home all axis
   Open port
   Turn on current

   For stations = 0 to 10 
      start = True

   'I need this backgroundworker to wait until it gets 
   'a temperature from backgroundworker 2 before moving
   'on to the next station

   next

end sub

backgroundworker2.dowork

  if start = true then  

    measure temperature 
    wait until the temperature stabilizes 
    store temperature to array

  endif

end sub
```

How would I wait until backgroundworker2 finishes for the for loop in backgroundworker1 moves on to the next step?

Comment: There may be a better way to do what you want overall but, based on what you currently have, you should look at the `WaitHandle` class. It has a number of derived classes that are used for synchronising multiple threads. You should read about the options but, without having touched that sort of stuff for some time, the `AutoResetEvent` is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using a thread.sleep inside of a do loop that checks for the completion of the temperature stabilization. It moves on to the next part of the thread once the do loop exits.